# Excercise 5.D.4 from M.Isaacs Finite Group Theory and Tate's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

I try to solve the following problem, wich related with Tate's theorem.

> Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of finite group $G$ and assume that
>   $P\subseteq K\subseteq G$. Show that $O^p(K)\subseteq K\cap O^p(G)$
>   and if equality holds then  $A^p(K) = K\cap A^p(G)$.

I explain the definitions. Here $O^p(G)$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that the corresponding factor group is a $p$-group. And $A^p(G) = G'O^p(G)$.

I can prove that $O^p(K)\subseteq O^p(G)\cap K$. But I stuck with the **second part**.

Also I recall that the inverse implication 
$$
A^p(K) = A^p(G)\cap K \Rightarrow O^p(K) = K\cap O^p(G)
$$
is known as Tate's Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier than Tate's Theorem. $O^p(K) = K \cap O^p(G)$ says that the largest quotients of $G$ and $K$ that are $p$-groups are isomorphic, in which case the largest quotients that are abelian $p$-groups are also isomorphic, which is equivalent to $A^p(K) = K \cap A^p(G)$. Here is a formal proof.

\begin{eqnarray*}O^p(K) = K \cap O^p(G) &\Rightarrow& K/O^p(K) = K/(K \cap O^p(G)) \cong\\
 KO^p(G)/O^p(G) = G/O^p(G) &\Rightarrow& K/A^p(K) = K/K'O^p(K) \cong\\
 G/G'O^p(G) = KA^p(G)/A^p(G) &\cong& K/(K \cap A^p(G)),\end{eqnarray*}.

Since $A^p(K) \le K \cap A^p(G)$, this implies that we have equality.

Comment: thank you very much! I understand your formal proof and beleive in the unformal proof) But for me it is not evident the fact that if the largest quotients of $G$ and $K$ that are $p$-groups are isomorphic, then the largest quotients that are abelian $p$-groups are also isomorphic.

Comment: But the largest abelian $p$-quotient is just the largest abelian quotient of the largest $p$-quotient.

Comment: Yes, and also is a largest $p$-quotient of the largest abelian quotient)